# Automatic User Gallery

Tags: media

Is there a module (or combination of) that will create a personal, but public, user gallery upon user registration automatically? Ideally with a link to the gallery from their profile?

Comment: Hi Calvin.  If all you need is a gallery of registered users with perhaps their photos and usernames, with a link to the gallery for all to see, it seems the views module would be enough.  Have you worked with the views module yet?  If that isn't what you're looking for, it would really help to be more specific about the functionality you're hoping to see...

Comment: Hello and Welcome to Drupal Stack Exchange. I would suggest you to get it started. You will find many posts explaining specific setups for gallery sites (slideshows, user registration, etc) - It's your site so you have to build it using tools you have - modules can't do it automagically for you.